# Python : How to parse a date in this format 'Mon, 04 Aug 2014 10:26:20 GMT'?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

How can I parse a datetime string in this format 'Mon, 04 Aug 2014 10:26:20 GMT' to compare it to the current date ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. How did you use https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(a, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 4, 10, 26, 20)
```

This will convert your string to `datetime` object which you can use for further process.